# return mysql_fetch_assoc results as an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to retreive results from a mysql query as an array. Here is a sample of the code :

```
function get_view_options($table) {
    include('config.php');
    $conn = new mysqli($sql['host'],$sql['username'],$sql['password'],$sql['database']);
    if ($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $query = "SELECT name FROM options WHERE page='".$table."' AND type='view' AND value='1'";
    $options = $conn->query($query)->fetch_assoc();
    $conn->close();
    return $options;
}
$options = get_view_options($page);
```

Here is the result I get from `print_r ($options);` :
**Array ( [name] => location )**

Here is what I was hoping to get :
**Array ( [0] => location [1] => owner [2] => id )**

Any suggestion on how I can achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure where the data your asking from is coming from, but try `SELECT *` to select all of the data from the table and `fetch_row()` instead of `fetch_assoc()` to have a numerically indexed row.

Comment: What is owner, id? These are fields?

Comment: I'm guessing you want 3 rows, not just one. Use [fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead, which will return all of the results.

Comment: use fetch_all() to get all results, or alternatively use a loop to continuously `fetch_assoc()` until all the rows are used up. You can find lots of examples online of how to correctly fetch results using mysqli already, I'm a bit surprised we need to repeat it here.

Comment: Iterate with `fetch_array` or use `fetch_all`

Comment: @aynber it's almost that, fetch_all does provide an array of arrays tho. I used select name in my sql query to only get this column's value. Can I reformat the nested array to only get the values in a single array ?

Comment: You'll have to create a new array for that type of structure. You can either use a while loop with fetch_assoc, or you can use a foreach with fetch_all.

Comment: @aynber '$options = array();
    foreach(get_view_options($page) as $option){
        array_push($options,$option[0]);
    }' did the trick. thanks for your help. Please the answer so I can selected it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @aynber!
Here is the final code with fetch_all()

```
<?php
    function get_view_options($table) {
        include('config.php');
        $conn = new mysqli($sql['host'],$sql['username'],$sql['password'],$sql['database']);
        if ($conn->connect_error){
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $query = "SELECT name FROM options WHERE page='".$table."' AND type='view' AND value='1'";
        $options = $conn->query($query)->fetch_all();//changed from fetch_assoc()

        $conn->close();
        return $options;
    }
    //We create an array with all the results
    $options = array();
    foreach(get_view_options($page) as $option){
        array_push($options,$option[0]);
    }
    print_r ($options);
?>
```

Which outputs : **Array ( [0] => location [1] => owner [2] => id )**